# Command substitution in quotes cannot be used to call the variable

Tags: shell, command-substitution, indirection

Say:

```
variable="Something that it holds"
```

then
`echo "$variable"` will output: Something that it holds

But say I also do:

```
var2="variable";  
echo "\$$(echo $var2)"
```

will just output: `$variable`
And not: Something that it holds

Can anyone tell me about what feature of Unix is in play, here?

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? Are you OK with `echo "$(echo $var2)"`? Incidentally you should also quote the `$var2`. So it becomes `echo "$(echo "$var2")"`. However in this example it won't matter (the bug is latent).

Comment: Sorry, it's just that,`"\$$(echo $var2)"` would evaluate to '$variable'. So why doesn't UNIX understand that I'm trying to do echo $variable (indirectly), and print out whatever is stored in variable. I'm referring to the second part

Comment: You should be very glad that the shell works the way it does -- it would be impossible to write a shell script that securely handled untrusted data if data were silently treated as code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy haha, maybe. I just wanted to know what was going on behind the scenes with Linux.

Comment: Sure. But the answer is just that there's _less_ going on behind the scenes that you expect; whatever extra step might have to happen to make the second `$variable` be replaced with a value just doesn't happen, because it's not part of the execution model to re-evaluate expansion results as code (unless the user runs `eval` or such). So we can't really give you an answer that says "it doesn't parse as code because thing-X happens", when the reality is more like "it doesn't parse as code because in order for that to happen, there would need to be step-Y, and that just isn't part of the model".

Comment: BTW, you may find https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser useful reading.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> variable="Something"
> var2="variable";
> echo "\$$(echo $var2)"
> ```

In the last line, you expect `"\$$(echo $var2)"` → `$variable` → `Something`.
This would require the shell to perform two parameter expansions. It does not, but rather simply prints the result of the command substitution `$(echo $var2)` prepended by a `$`.

In principle, **eval** helps you to get what you want. After the shell performs the first step, `"\$$(echo $var2)"` → `$variable`, eval performs the second step, `$variable` → `Something`.

```
$ eval echo "\$$(echo $var2)"
Something
```

Although in our particular case the above command is OK, that still lacks a correct quoting, and [`printf` is to be favored over `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803),

```
$ eval 'printf "%s\n" "${'"$var2"'}"'
Something
```

However, eval raises security concerns with untrusted data. Suppose
`var2="variable;rm importantFile"`. In that case, eval passes

```
echo $variable;rm importantFile
```

to the shell, which happily removes `importantFile`, if it exists.

In some shells (e.g.: Bash, ksh, Zsh) you can also do it using **indirection**. The syntax of indirect expansion in Bash is:

```
$ echo "${!var2}"
Something
```

`var2="variable;rm importantFile"` is not a problem anymore,
but `var2='a[$(rm importantFile)]'` still is.

Read more about indirection in the [Bash manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation
> point (!), and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection.
> Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new parameter;
> this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion,
> rather than the expansion of the original parameter

Comment: `bash`'s `${!var}` is doing almost the opposite of what `${!var}` was doing in `ksh93`. In `ksh93`, to do indirection, you'd use namerefs (not `${!var}` which is to *prevent* indirection when `var` is a nameref, try `ksh93 -c 'a=value; nameref b=a; echo "$b" "${!b}"'`). In `zsh`, it's `${(P)var}`

Answer (score 8):

Smells like an anti-pattern(*). Many shells have string-indexed arrays/dictionaries. In `ksh93` (where that syntax comes from), `bash` or `zsh`:

```
typeset -A dictionary
x="keyX"
y="keyY"
dictionary[keyX]="valueX"
dictionary[$y]="valueY"

printf '%s\n' "${dictionary[$x]}"
printf '%s\n' "${dictionary[keyY]}"
```

(*) Nothing to do with Linux per se. The variable-name-in-a-variable is a very general ["anti-pattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980601/what-is-an-anti-pattern#98061), something that shouldn't be done, and if you think you need it, there is a problem with your design ([XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))? Most uses of a variable-name-in-a-variable are better replaced with a dictionary when that exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started learning Unix last week, and didn't completely grasp what you're trying to say. Are you telling about the inner working of UNIX? Though, I got the dictionary part

Comment: See footnote in answer.

Comment: Right, actually, maybe you're right. I wasn't trying to solve a problem. It's just that I wanted to know what is going on, behind the scenes, with Linux's interpretation and all that. But thank you for mentioning that it's not usually necessary to do so

Comment: It's not _always_ an anti-pattern. For example, M (a non-relational database language) and its descendant ObjectScript offer `@variable` syntax to do just this, which is very useful for passing around references to database nodes. The alternative would be `Merge`ing the entire data tree into an in-memory node, editing it and `Merge`ing it back into the database, which for a large data node is hugely inefficient.

Comment: Also, in bash, indirect references are genuinely essential in some cases. You can't pass an associative array as a function argument without one, for example. Particularly in bash releases which have formally adopted the ksh nameref feature, I absolutely disagree with the antipattern claim.

Answer (score 5):

What you are observing is the [standard behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01) of a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell: in general, it

1. reads its input;
2. breaks the input into tokens: words and operators ([token recognition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03));

   - during this step, any time it encounters an *unquoted* `$` (or `` ` ``), it recursively determines the type of expansion and the token to be expanded, reading all the needed input;
3. parses the input into simple commands and compound commands;
4. performs various [expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) (separately) on different parts of each command, resulting in a list of pathnames and fields to be treated as a command and arguments;
5. performs redirection and removes redirection operators and their operands from the parameter list;
6. executes a function, built-in, executable file, or script;
7. optionally waits for the command to complete and collects the exit status.

When parsing `echo "\$$(echo $var2)"`, the shell detects two expansions (step 2): the double-quoted command substitution `$(echo $var2)` and the unquoted parameter expansion `$var2`. The escaped `$` in `\$` is taken as a literal dollar sign because a double-quoted `\` retains its role as an [escape character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) when followed by `$`.

No further detection of expansions happens at later stages. Specifically, there is no further parsing of the result of expansions performed in step 4 (`"\$$(echo $var2)"` → `"\$$(echo variable)"` → `"\$variable"` → `$variable`) that could detect expansion-triggering characters.

Also note that, while the `$` symbol is used to replace the name of a variable with its content in the context of parameter expansion, it has not been designed as a general [dereference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

In [standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), whose simplest form is *`${parameter}`*, the *`parameter`* specification is only allowed to be a variable name, a positional parameter or a special parameter (see the [definition of "parameter"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267)). Strictly speaking, parameter expansions can not be nested (an expansion expression is only allowed as *`word`* in the various *`${parameter<symbols>[word]}`* forms).

You can easily verify that, with the [exception of the Z shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), `${${foo}}` is not a valid expression and that `$$` expands to the shell's PID (thus, `$foo` expands to the value of `foo`, `$$foo` expands to the concatenation of the shell's PID and the literal "foo", `$$$foo` expands to the concatenation of the shell's PID and the value of `foo`, ...).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to indirect variable expansion, in bash (starting from version 4.3) you can use a **nameref**

```bsh
declare -n var2="variable"  # "var2" is a _reference_ to "variable"

variable="Something"
echo "$var2"     # => Something

variable="something else"
echo "$var2"     # => something else

unset variable
echo "$var2"     # => ""
```

---

I don't know how this is implemented, but this is an interesting tidbit: you can find out what a nameref refers to using indirection:

```bsh
echo ${!var2}    # => variable
```